# Size of largest fiber

Tags: general-topology, fiber-bundles

Suppose I have a map $f\colon X\to Y$ with finite fibers (where $X,Y$ are simply topological spaces for now, although maybe it's better to think of schemes). Is there a name for the quantity $\sup_{y\in Y}|f^{-1}(y)|$?

In particular, is there a relationship between this quantity and the relative dimension of $f$?

Comment: The relative dimension of $f$ is $0$ in this case (the fibers are all $0$-dimensional).

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I want to know if there is an analogous notion that captures the relative increase in cardinality. For instance consider a finite-sheeted covering.

Comment: Well you asked about the relationship between this quantity and the relative dimension, so that was unclear. Regardless, in nice enough situations (and many that you will encounter in practice), the quantity you describe will be the degree. In slightly more general situations it will be called the separable degree.